# css file not updating when I save scss file

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, sass

I have been having some issues with my css not updating when I save a file. I thought it was a problems with the VSCode live sass compiler at first because the changes only updated if I restarted the compiler but I have just made a change to the main scss file and the change showed instantly.

I think there may either be an issue with the main file or the header file.

I know this may be a typo or something i'm not doing right but it has been an issue of days and I can't work it out. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Main file :

```
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
@import "./Header";
```

header file :

```
.header {
  height: 8vh;
  background-color: #131921;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  background-color: hotpink;

  &__logo {
    width: 100px;
    // object-fit: contain;
    margin: 0 20px;
  }

  &__search {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 35px;
  }

  &__searchIcon {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 36px !important;
    width: 36px !important;
    background-color: #cd9042;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0 !important;
  }

  &__searchInput {
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px !important;
  }

  &__nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  &__boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-align: left;
  }

  &__boxesFirstLine {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }

  &__boxesSecondLine {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 9px;
  }

  &__basketText {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 9px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
}
```

the header file is called Header.scss.

I don't know what would be preventing updates when the compiler is running but is fine if it is restarted. I have asked the extension devs and asked specifically on here whether it is an issue with the extension but had none responses.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend `parcel.js` to automatically convert on hit save. Also `parcel.js` so smart about adding packages, converting than any other bundler stuff.

`"build": "parcel styles/main.scss"` Add this script to the package.json file. Let the parcel convert for you into realtime when press save.

Comment: so there is nothing wrong with my scss I just need to use some other compiler?

Comment: It's not about the compiler, the compiler does the work correctly but different variation/mode.  
In parcel, compile only the main file and don't need to compile all the files also look into it what changes. And then, whatever file you `@import` into the main file, it will compile into a single CSS file.
For module system/nested structure, parcel better choice to handle.

Comment: Yeah.... I don't really understand what you are getting at. Do you know why it's not working the way I am doing it?

Comment: Yes, I have figured out the problem. Via vscode ext, every sass file compiles separately. So if you made changes header, navbar, footer file that changes doesn't add to the main file in realtime. when you hit restart, the main file looks for changes and it's get updated.

Comment: Legend. Okay is there a work around. Other than using a seperate compiler

Comment: of course, you can read the documentation of that ext. https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md